# Loop selected over nodes and select subnodes at any level within first node

Tags: r, xml2

I am using the xml2 package.  I want to:

1. Select nodes with a particular tag (in this case all `envelope`)
2. Loop over these nodes and select nodes within regardless of nesting (in this case all `value` tags found inside of `card-entry` tags)
3. Concatenate the text with a space

There are three envelopes so I'd expect to be able to return a vector of three with allt he text from within `value` tags found inside of `card-entry` tags.  I can not accomplish this.  How can I accomplish this?  Why do my approaches below not work?

### MWE

```
library(xml2)

myxml <- read_xml('
<inside>
 <box>
   <card-entry>
     <card-id type="integer">605383</card-id>
     <value>get well</value>
   </card-entry>
 </box>
 <envelope>
     <card-entry>
       <card-id type="integer">605380</card-id>
       <value>coke</value>
     </card-entry>
     <card-entry>
       <card-id type="integer">610954</card-id>
       <value>pizza</value>
     </card-entry>  
     <card-entry>
       <card-id type="integer">605381</card-id>
       <value>surprise</value>
     </card-entry>
     <card-entry>
       <card-id type="integer">610958</card-id>
       <value>joke</value>
       <random>true</random>
     </card-entry> 
 </envelope>
 <envelope>
     <card-entry>
       <card-id type="integer">605381</card-id>
       <value>charlie horse</value>
     </card-entry>
     <card-entry>
       <card-id type="integer">605380</card-id>
       <value>rug bug</value>
     </card-entry>
     <subenvelope>
       <value>dont get me</value>
     </subenvelope>
     <card-entry>
       <card-id type="integer">610954</card-id>
       <value>mario cart</value>
     </card-entry>  
 </envelope>
 <envelope>
     <card-entry>
       <card-id type="integer">605377</card-id>
       <value>trogdor</value>
     </card-entry>
     <subenvelope>
       <card-entry>
         <card-id type="integer"></card-id>
         <value>jorb</value>
       </card-entry>
     </subenvelope>
     <card-entry>
       <card-id type="integer">605333</card-id>
       <value></value>
     </card-entry>    
 </envelope>
</inside>
'
)
```

## Desired output

```
## [1] coke pizza surprise joke
## [2] charlie horse rug bug mario cart
## [3] trogdor jorb
```

## What I tried

```
children <- lapply(xml2::xml_find_all(myxml, '//envelope'), xml2::xml_children)

rm_na <- function(x) x[!is.na(x)]

lapply(children, function(x){

    paste(rm_na(unlist(xml2::xml_text(xml2::xml_child(x, '//card-entry//value')))), collapse = ' ')

})

## [[1]]
## [1] ""
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] ""
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] ""
## 
## There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)


lapply(children, function(x){

    paste(rm_na(unlist(xml2::xml_text(xml2::xml_find_all(x, '//card-entry//value')))), collapse = ' ')

})

## [[1]]
## [1] "get well coke pizza surprise joke charlie horse rug bug mario cart trogdor jorb "
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "get well coke pizza surprise joke charlie horse rug bug mario cart trogdor jorb "
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "get well coke pizza surprise joke charlie horse rug bug mario cart trogdor jorb "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your inner selector, you want to make it relative to the current node, so you want `.//` rather than `//` which would search the whole tree again

```
sapply(xml_find_all(myxml,"//envelope"), function(x) 
  paste(xml_text(xml_find_all(x, ".//card-entry/value")), collapse=" ")
)

# [1] "coke pizza surprise joke"        
# [2] "charlie horse rug bug mario cart"
# [3] "trogdor jorb "
```